# Defining defaults in regular routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I add this line in my routes.rb file

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id/:title', :controller => "recipes"
```

thinking that I am adding the recipe title at the end of the URL and this would only apply to the recipe controller. I have also declared a resource at the beginning of the file like this

```
map.resources :recipes
```

The following URL works perfectly fine

```
http://localhost:3000/recipes/show/84/testing201
http://localhost:3000/recipes/edit/84/testing2010
```

However, when I say rake routes I get the following for the recipe controller

```
recipes GET    /recipes(.:format)                 {:controller=>"recipes", :action=>"index"}
             POST   /recipes(.:format)                 {:controller=>"recipes", :action=>"create"}
  new_recipe GET    /recipes/new(.:format)             {:controller=>"recipes", :action=>"new"}
 edit_recipe GET    /recipes/:id/edit(.:format)        {:controller=>"recipes", :action=>"edit"}
      recipe GET    /recipes/:id(.:format)             {:controller=>"recipes", :action=>"show"}
             PUT    /recipes/:id(.:format)             {:controller=>"recipes", :action=>"update"}
             DELETE /recipes/:id(.:format)             {:controller=>"recipes", :action=>"destroy"}
```

and at the bottom I see this

```
/:controller/:action/:id/:title    
/:controller/:action/:id           
/:controller/:action/:id(.:format)
```

From the output it seems like the title is not applied to the recipe route but it is applied at a global level. How can I fix this, so the wildcard symbol (":title" in "/:controller/:action/:id/:title") is only applicable to the recipes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two different routing concepts. One is RESTful routes (go read about it on google) and the other is generic/general route. You should use just one of them. RESTful one is recommended (`map.resources :recipes`). But first you need to decide which one to use.

Plus this definition is wrong:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id/:title', :controller => "recipes"
```

You have :controller variable in the routes and then you say that :controller should be bound to 'recipes'. One way to fix it is this:

```
map.connect '/recipes/:action/:id', :controller => "recipes"
```

or better

```
map.connect '/recipes/:id/:action', :controller => "recipes"
```

and you're getting closer to RESTful routes.

If you want the title in your routes, then go with named route coupled with RESTful resource. But don't mix `:id` and `:title` in one route. Use just one parameter (or both combined but that's another story).

```
map.resources :recipes, :except => [:show]
map.recipe '/recipe/:title', :controller => 'recipes', :action => 'show'
```

And you would probably need to override the `to_param` method in your `Recipe` model:

```
def Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
     title
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, it works expected. However, the default edit link(http://localhost:3000/recipes/84/edit/) results in an error. It looks like it is trying the "show" action instead of the "edit". 

map.resources :recipes, :except => [:show]
map.recipe '/recipes/:id/:title', :controller => "recipes", :action => "show" 
Any ideas?

Comment: /recipes/:id/:title -> again, this is wrong; use either :id or :title and use singular form, so it does not conflict with map.recipes, like this: `map.recipe '/recipe/:id', :controller => 'recipes', :action => 'show'

Comment: I don't think I should move away from the defaults that rails provide. So I have decided to change the format of the show url to something like this http://localhost:3000/recipes/84-testing2010. I provided my own definition of to_param and this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

i would comment the map.resources, comment the connect and do it one more time with map.with_options:

```
map.with_options :controller => 'recipes' do |recipes|
 recipes.list '', :action => 'index'
 recipes.delete '/delete/:id/:title', :action => 'delete'
 recipes.edit '/edit/:id/:title', :action => 'edit'
end
```

Comment: I think it's best to stick with the RESTful way of doing things. I just changed the format of the URL (localhost:3000/recipes/84-testing2010) and this seems to work fine.